# String or binary data would be truncated with CONVERT function

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I've been trying to make an insert query to SQL Server using PHP PDO but getting an error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: 
>   
> String or binary data would be truncated.

I am using PDO driver for connection and trying to make a prepared statement. My login and password data are stored as Binary in the database table so I have to run the query with the `CONVERT` function it looks like this:

```
$status = DB::query("user", 
    "INSERT INTO dbo.acctable (id,password,accounttype,birthdate,email)
       VALUES ((CONVERT(binary, :loginid)), (CONVERT(binary, :pass)), 
      :acctype, :bdate, :email)", 
    [
    "loginid" => 'testuser',
    "pass" => '123456',
    "email" => "testemail@gmail.com",
    "acctype" => "0",
    "bdate" => "1/01/1950"
]);
```

However I can run this query without any error in a static way like this:

```
$status = DB::query("user", 
    "INSERT INTO dbo.acctable(id,password,accounttype,birthdate,email) 
       VALUES ((CONVERT(binary, 'testuser')), (CONVERT(binary, '123456')), 
      :acctype, :bdate, :email)", 
    [
    "email" => "testemail@gmail.com",
    "acctype" => "0",
    "bdate" => "1/01/1950"
]);
```

My `DB::query` method looks like this:

```
public static function query($type, $query, $params = array())
{
    $statement = self::$type()->prepare($query);
    $status = $statement->execute($params);
}
```

Comment: `binary` with no length? What is the definition of the table (what are the sizes of `id` and `password`)? What are the max lengths of strings that are passed into `:loginid` and `:pass`? How is this enforced? Truncation could also be happening in a trigger. Also, on more modern versions of SQL Server, you'll get a [much better error message](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2019/03/how-to-fix-the-error-string-or-binary-data-would-be-truncated/) (though you may need trace flag 460).

Comment: [link](https://abload.de/img/adszjyjwe.png) this is how the table design looks like. I tried to add `OPTION (QUERYTRACEON 460)` at the end of the query but the error message didn't changed.

Comment: There are multiple problems. First, observe what happens if you put an `nvarchar` string (which I suspect PDO is doing) into binary(13), then try to get it back out that way. `SELECT CONVERT(nvarchar(255), CONVERT(binary(13), N'testuser'));` Notice a problem? Also for birthdate why use smalldatetime when date exists? And is varchar(50) really big enough for all possible e-mails? I don't think so. The min you need to support is 320 IMHO.

Comment: First of all thank you for the feedback. I tried to run query you said and it returns: `array(1) { [0]=> array(2) { [""]=> string(7) "testuse" [0]=> string(7) "testuse" } } ` when I var_dump the result. Well yeah things you said about e-mail and birtdate are very logical and it definetaly should be done that way but it's not me who designed the database. It is actually an online game's database so changing those values can break the server or client I think so this is why I'm trying to work this way.